# C# -Launch Catia by opening a CatPart

Tags: c#, catia

I am working on Catia V5 automation and have a requirement to launch Catia by clicking a CatPart/ CatProduct if Catia is not already running. I tried the below code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @filepath; 
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But I get error: 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An error occurred in sending the command to the application

Can anybody help how to solve as this code works on my machine but not in other machine. 
I have Catia v5 and 3dexp installed so when I tried to create instance of Catia application it opens 3d experience.

```
System.Type objBLType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Catia.Application");
object objBL = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objBLType);
```

Comment: Please share the full exception log.

Comment: 2018-11-26 11:43:00.702 [ERROR]   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An error occurred in sending the command to the application
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at AttributeExtraction.CATIAEngine.StartCatiaApplication(String filepath) in D:\Projects\AttributeExtraction\AttributeExtraction\CATIAEngine.cs:line 206

Comment: Does CATIA get's launched ? Or the code fail to start even the CATIA process ?

Comment: The startup window of Catia appears but then suddenly a pop up" Catia has stopped working" and then I have to close the program.

Comment: Check the file associations. For win10 Default App Settings-> Choose Default apps by file type. Make sure CatPart / CatProduct are associated with CATIA.

Comment: Also, just try running the application as Administrator

Comment: It works perferctly in my machine- Win10 with Process.Start, but not in my colleague and a VM which is Win7. When i tried running the app as admin i get the following error in log and it does not launch Catia:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184268/discussion-between-praveen-rai-and-sina123).